# Suggest an algorithm for color pattern matching against a large known set

Tags: c#, algorithm, opencv, hashtable, knn

I have a requirement that calls for matching a Sample Set of color values against a Known Set of values to find either an exact match, or matches that are within an acceptable distance. I'm not entirely sure what algorithm would be best suited for this and I'm looking for suggestions.

I thought about using a SQL query as I think this would be a straightforward approach, however, ideally this would be done in-memory on the application server or even on a GPU for maximum speed.

**Example**:

Let's say we are given a set of three RGB color values, two blues and an orange:

**Sample Set:**

Color 1: 81,177,206 (blue)

Color 2: 36, 70, 224 (blue)

Color 3: 255, 132, 0 (orange)

This set of 3 color values must be matched against a much larger set of color values to see if this set exists within it, either with the same exact RGB values for each of the 3 colors - or - if any pattern exists where an RGB value of the colors varies by an acceptable degree. Let's assume any of the RGB components can be up to 3 digits higher or lower in value.

Let's say our big set of known color values that we'll search against looks like this:

**Known Set:**

```
            Color 1          Color 2       Color 3
Sample A: [25, 25, 25],    [10, 10, 10], [100, 100, 100] 

Sample B: [125, 125, 125], [10, 10, 10], [200, 200, 200] 

Sample C: [13, 87, 255],   [10, 10, 10], [100, 100, 100] 

Sample D: [67, 111, 0],    [10, 10, 10], [200, 200, 200] 

Sample E: [255, 255, 255], [10, 10, 10], [100, 100, 100]
```

Given this scenario, we would find zero matches when we run our sample set against it, because none of the known colors have a Color 1 that is anywhere close to our sample set values. However, let's add another color to the Known Set that *would* return a positive match:

```
Sample F: [81,177,206], [36, 70, 224], [255, 132, 0]
```

If Sample F existed with these values in the Known Set, we would get a positive hit, because it's the exact RGB values as Color 1 in our Sample Set. Also, we need to accept a varying degree of differences in the RGB values, so the following would also return positive hits because each RGB value is within 3 digits from Color 1's values from the Sample Set:

**Positive hits**: (remember Color 1 is: 81,177,206)

Sample F: **80**,177,206 (red channel is 1 digit away)

Sample F: 81,**175**,**204** (green and blue channels 2 digits away)

Sample F: **82,179,208** (all three channels within 3 digits away)

However, if the distance is too great, then a match would not be found. Any RGB component must be within 3 digits to trigger a positive result. So if Sample F looked like the following, we would **not** get a positive result because the distance is too great:

**Negative hits:**

Sample F: **85**,177,206 (red channel is 4 digits away)

Sample F: 81,**170**,206 (green channel is 7 digits away)

Sample F: 81,177,**200** (blue channel is 6 digits away)

So far we've just taken Color 1 from the Sample Set into consideration. However the requirement calls for taking the entire Sample Set into consideration. So if no positive matches can be found for Color 1, then we assume no match at all and don't consider Colors 2 and 3 from the Sample Set.

However, if we find a positive result for Color 1, let's say 80,177,206 which is just 1 digit off in the Red channel 80 vs 81, then we **do** continue processing Color 2, and if we find a positive match for that then we process Color 3 and so on.

What are your suggestions for the algorithm best suited for this problem? I need something that will allow the Known Set to scale very large without too much of a performance hit. There will probably be 1M+ samples in the Known Set at scale.

I thought about using hashtables, one per Color to construct the Known Set. So I could test for a match on Color 1, and if found, test the hashtable for Color 2, and stop when I find no more hits. If I got through all 3 colors/hashtables with positive hits, then I'd have an overall positive match, else I would not. However, this approach doesn't allow for the variance needed in each of the RGB channels for each color. There would be too many combinations to allow for constructing hashtables to hold it all.

Thanks in advance and thanks for reading this far down!

Comment: Is 3 the cumulative deviation allowed, or is it for each of the R, G, B values?

Comment: It's for each of the RGB values within each of the colors in the set. It's not a culmulative deviation although perhaps it's not a bad idea to have one as an extra safeguard.

Comment: Using OpenCV with C#? Using EmguCV I reckon?

Comment: What it you have several sets on the known set of colors that matches the criteria? How often do the known set changes, compared to the frequency of running this algorithm? Is the size of the allowed deviation fixed or can it change over time?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan Ideally, yes. I was trying to use the SurfFeature demo as a starting point. But that example compares Image A to Image B whereas I need to compare features of Image A with an entire known set in the database. I haven't been able to modify the SurfFeature sample to do that. If you could point me in the right direction I'd be enormously grateful.

Comment: @ZoharPeled As long as one sample in the Known Set matches (or is within the deviation on one or more of the RGB channels for the color being tested) it's an overall success. The Known Set will only grow over time. The deviation may be modified up or down a bit to solve for false positives/negatives. However, the deviation doesn't change in terms of running the algorithm. In other words if the deviation is 3, it's always 3 for every color/sample test until I decide to change it one day.

Comment: Is your color sets always going to contain 3 colors, or can it be any number of colors? (for example, if you store it in a database, will you have a 9 tinyint columns table? (each color has 3 tinyint columns)

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes, it will always have the same number of colors within a set. In terms of SQL you're correct.

Comment: Well dear I assume you haven't used EmguCV much. Just browse its website and you will get all the info. It has sample projects as well :)

Comment: @TalhaIrfan I've been through the site and have all of the samples. Please point me to one that uses GpuMat's for the reference images fed from a database. The problem is how to set it up so it's not comparing Image A to Image B, but rather Image A to n-Images, all using the GPU.

Comment: I've ported the logic over to Cudafy and ran it on my GPU. Turns out it's 50% slower on the GPU compared to PLINQ on the CPU. Hop over to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739044/cudafy-array-loop-50-slower-than-on-cpu if you're interested in figuring out how that's possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, after experimenting with SQL and GPU programming (Cudafy), the fastest, easiest, and most debuggable solution was to simply iterate through the data using Parallel.For(). This approach yielded 1.5M samples processed (90M total bytes) in 18ms.

Answer (score 2):

Keep one sorted list.  Sort it three times with a stable sort, first by B, then by G, then by R. This leaves it sorted in RGB order.   Given your input, find the indexes for the first and last acceptable R's with a binary search.  Then search that range for acceptable G's, then search the again reduced range for B's.   The whole thing should be O(lgN).

--
Unless I am missing something this solution generalizes to matching a set of 3 colors, or 10 colors or k colors.   Generate an array of indexes into your list of color sets. To prepare, stable sort the indexes 3*k times as above.  To seek, do 3*k binary searches in the opposite order.

(This assumes the colors are fixed into columns.  If they are not, you can still use this method, but your index list goes to N*k size: it needs an entry for A1, A2, A3. And at the end add a check that you have matched one from each column.)

Comment: Thanks - that only solves for one color within the sample set though. In the examples above that would work for, say Color 1, but I'd have to repeat it for Colors 2 and 3. What happens when I need to test 10 colors in a sample set?

Comment: So you have a large list of N sets, where each set has size k, and you only want to find a set where all k values are "close enough?"

Comment: I have a large list of N sets, where each set is constructed of a fixed size number of subsets (the 'colors' in the example above). Within each of those subsets are three int values (r, g, b). I need to find which sets from the large list have subsets whose rgb values are each within n-digits of the sample set but on a color-for-color basis.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description in the question and the conversation in the comments, why not use a simple stored procedure and a user defined type? with proper indexing there should be no performance problems. Assuming the color sets you want to compare contains multiple sets of 3 colors, I would probably do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE KnownColorSets (
   KC_1_R tinyint NOT NULL,
   KC_1_G tinyint NOT NULL,
   KC_1_B tinyint NOT NULL,
   KC_2_R tinyint NOT NULL,
   KC_2_G tinyint NOT NULL,
   KC_2_B tinyint NOT NULL,
   KC_3_R tinyint NOT NULL,
   KC_3_G tinyint NOT NULL,
   KC_3_B tinyint NOT NULL
)

CREATE TYPE CompareColorSet As TABLE 
(
   CC_1_R tinyint NOT NULL,
   CC_1_G tinyint NOT NULL,
   CC_1_B tinyint NOT NULL,
   CC_2_R tinyint NOT NULL,
   CC_2_G tinyint NOT NULL,
   CC_2_B tinyint NOT NULL,
   CC_3_R tinyint NOT NULL,
   CC_3_G tinyint NOT NULL,
   CC_3_B tinyint NOT NULL
)



CREATE PROCEDURE stpCompareColorSets 
(
    @Exists bit output,
    @CompareColorSet dbo.CompareColorSet readonly
)
AS
  DECLARE @MaxDiviation tinyint = 3 -- This may be taken from a General params table or added as a parameter to the stored procedure
  SET @Exists = 0
  IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM KnownColorSets KC INNER JOIN
    @CompareColorSet CC ON(
      KC_1_R BETWEEN CC_1_R - @MaxDiviation AND CC_1_R - @MaxDiviation
      AND KC_1_G BETWEEN CC_1_G - @MaxDiviation AND CC_1_G - @MaxDiviation
      AND KC_1_B BETWEEN CC_1_B - @MaxDiviation AND CC_1_B - @MaxDiviation

      AND KC_2_R BETWEEN CC_2_R - @MaxDiviation AND CC_2_R - @MaxDiviation
      AND KC_2_G BETWEEN CC_2_G - @MaxDiviation AND CC_2_G - @MaxDiviation
      AND KC_2_B BETWEEN CC_2_B - @MaxDiviation AND CC_2_B - @MaxDiviation

      AND KC_3_R BETWEEN CC_3_R - @MaxDiviation AND CC_3_R - @MaxDiviation
      AND KC_3_G BETWEEN CC_3_G - @MaxDiviation AND CC_3_G - @MaxDiviation
      AND KC_3_B BETWEEN CC_3_B - @MaxDiviation AND CC_3_B - @MaxDiviation
    )
  ) 
  SET @Exists = 1
```

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I'm trying right now. My feeling is that since the total row count in the table would be in the low millions and that SQL server is pretty efficient with query plans, that I have a much better chance of success with this route vs. using data structures in C# that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: sql's strength is working with large sets of data, and an order of magnitude of a few million is hardly breakfast for a well indexed sql server table. The other advantage is that you don't need to write the search algorithm yourself.

Comment: Turns out that SQL was the slowest method, followed by GPU (surprisingly), and the fastest method is PLINQ on the CPU.

Comment: @znelson: If you're referring to your recently deleted question, your kernel looked like it was memory bound and the GPU is probably slow because you have to copy the data over to the GPU. If the data resided on the GPU rather than the CPU, a GPU-based version would be more efficient. (also you had huge unrolled loops and were probably wasting memory bandwidth fetching instructions)

Comment: @znelson Did you have any indexes on your table and type?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I tried tests with and without indexes. They definitely improved the performance but the timing is still 250-300ms vs. PLINQ which is about 180ms-200ms.

Comment: @znelson I guess that PLINQ is a better solution then :-)